# Contingency Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, contingency

I am trying to construct a contingency matrix for instances between a caller and callee. I am just having issues because my variable caller_id contains values that are 5 numbers in length; however, I need to separate the values based on if they begin with 1, 2, or 3. For example, my data is of the pattern:

```
CALLER         CALLEE
12345            1
23456            1
35643            2
```

Where the prefix of Caller and the value for Callee could be 1, 2, or 3, representing 1 for of white ethnicity, 2 for of black ethnicity, and 3 for unknown. I need to then create a contingency matrix such as:

```
              White Caller     Black Caller
White Callee    # of calls    # of calls
Black Callee    # of calls    # of calls
Unknown Callee  # of calls    # of calls
```

If anyone has any advice on how I could go about separating the values and creating the matrix, it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R you may use

```
with(df, table(CALLER = substr(CALLER, 0, 1), CALLEE))
#       CALLEE
# CALLER 1 2
#      1 1 0
#      2 1 0
#      3 0 1
```

where `substr(df$CALLER, 0, 1)` extracts the first digit from `df$CALLER` (see `?substr`) and then `table` gives the contingency table.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to add the labels for all values such as above?

Comment: Sure, there are multiple ways to do that. If you have only those three possible options, then simply `colnames(tb) <- c("White Caller", "Black Caller")` and similarly with `rownames(tb)` would work, where `tb <- with(df, table(CALLER = substr(CALLER, 0, 1), CALLEE))`.